# How to avoid copying list element's name to column names using write.xlsx?

Tags: r, list

I have a large list called myList with m elements(lists) to be exported into m excel files. In each file, there will be length(names(myList[[m]])) sheets where each myList[[m]][i] is a also a list. The following function work well but, in every final sheet, the myList[[m]][i] name is added to the original column name as prefix. How can I remove them and make my columns names stay as initial? Any help is appreciated!

```
lapply( names(myList[[m]]), function(nam) write.xlsx2( myList[[m]][nam], file=excel,sheetName=paste0(m,"_",nam),append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE))
```

Comment: Try using `myList[[m]][[nam]]` (double-brackets around `nam`).

Comment: Hello r2even, It works like a magic. Thank you! Could you please further explain why it is like this?

Comment: It worked with my data. Perhaps you could provide a small sample of your data so we can stop speculating.

Comment: Sorry r2even, I edited my first response. It did work!!! Was my bad that I did not change all of them.

Comment: When dealing with a `list`, a single bracket always returns a list, but you want the object inside; a double bracket always returns the object inside (but can only do so for a single item). With `x <- list(1, 2, 3)`, see the difference between `str(x[1])` and `str(x[[1]])`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you r2evans.